# How to view two Layouts in one Activity?

Tags: android

Is there any way to make this possible? I'm using Inflate but its not working. So did anyone have any other way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [two different layouts for one activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063902/two-different-layouts-for-one-activity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

**1.**  [merging layouts, as describrd in Android Developers Resources](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html).

**2.**  [Using two layout xml file for one Activity](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/UsingtwolayoutxmlfileforoneActivity.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show like two different layout in screen, just use fragments. That is the proper way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**use  LayoutInflater**

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = vi.inflate(R.layout.Second,null);
```