# Android Studio - should each layout have a class?

Tags: layout

I'm beginner to Android Studio and was wondering in general should each layout page of your app have a class associated with it? Or can you have a single class controlling multiple layouts?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you make a layout with widgets or components you will need to link it to a class to use them. So to use any layout yes you need to attach a class to it, but you don't necessarily need a new class for every layout. You can have one class use multiple layouts. But not simultaneously.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063902/two-different-layouts-for-one-activity)